# "OnDeviceRecognition" in Speech kit not working

Tags: ios13

In ios13 beta apple support on device speech recognition.

In documentation I observed to set "requiresOnDeviceRecognition" property as true, then audio will be converted as text in device only.

But whenever I set this property as "Yes" , I always getting this error :

> Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=1103 "No models installed yet" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=No models installed yet}
>       NSLocalizedFailureReason = "No models installed yet";

Comment: From what I've seen, also note that `supportsOnDeviceRecognition` being `true` depends on the local identifier (thus the language) you are using. Typically english will be OK but french will not (at least on iPhoneX iOS 13.3.1)

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure that you're passing the correct locale in the `SFSpeechRecognizer`.

For example, I live in India, my current device language is English(India), so I've initialized the `SFSpeechRecognizer` in the following way:

```
private let speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "en_IN"))!
```

This should work for you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you didn't check the SFSpeechRecognizer's `supportsOnDeviceRecognition`. If it is `false` you cannot ask for on-device recognition.